# Will this jinja template code snippet work properly on both a windows and linux server?

Tags: flask, templates, jinja2, cross-platform

```
<img src="{{ './static/images/' ~ fruit.image_name }}">
```

I am concerned because I hard-coded the forward slashes into the path as shown between the single quotes above.  If this is a legitimate concern, is there a jinja function similar to python's **os.path.join()** function that can be used?

Comment: The use of forward slashes in your path is not of concern as this is a url path and not a file system path.